# Implementing custom XSD facet with Xerces?

Tags: java, xsd, xerces2-j

Does Xerces parser support the implementation of custom facets?

I am looking at Xerces documentation to try add a custom facet for XSD validation, but I don't find anything specific, and I'm unsure where to start.

**Edit**:

One possibility might be to use an appinfo annotation to describe a facet, and perform additional validation when the XML is being parsed.